# How can I use linerenderer with world space and to be able to change the lines positions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that when I'm drawing triangles by looping over vertices it seems that most of the triangles or all of them are completed but I can't move the lines since it's in world space.

If I set the world space to be false then I can move the lines but then also the triangles are not completed drawn.

The first screenshot is when the world space set to true:
The bottom trinalges seems to be under 0 under the terrain.
But I can't move them up since world space of the linerenderer is true.

[image: triangles world of space is true]

The second screenshot is when world space set to false I can move the lines but this time it seems that all the triangles are not completed drawn:

[image: triangles world space set to false]

This is the script I'm using to draw the triangles:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject meshPrefab;
    public Vector3[] newVertices;
    public Vector2[] newUV;
    public int[] newTriangles;

    private List<Vector3> verticesList = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<Vector2> uvsList = new List<Vector2>();
    private List<int> trianglesList = new List<int>();

    private void Start()
    {
        Mesh meshprefab = meshPrefab.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        newVertices = meshprefab.vertices;
        newTriangles = meshprefab.triangles;

        for (int i = 0; i < newVertices.Length - 2; i++)
        {
            DrawLine(newVertices[i], newVertices[i + 1], Color.red);
            DrawLine(newVertices[i + 1], newVertices[i + 2], Color.red);
            DrawLine(newVertices[i + 2], newVertices[i], Color.red);
        }
    }

    void DrawLine(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color, float duration = 0.2f)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
        myLine.transform.position = start;
        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.endColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 0.1f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.1f;
        lr.useWorldSpace = false;
        lr.SetPosition(0, start);
        lr.SetPosition(1, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a constant value to all your vertex points when drawing in order to move the lines around in world space.

Comment: @Draco18s Moving aorund in world space I mean in scene view. I want to move them also in game when the game is running but first in scene view.  What value should I add ? And should I do it in the Update ?

Comment: You would use a transform for those values.